# Probability: Simple problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given **n probabilities**, each describing the probability to rain on the n-th day. The probabilites for rain are indepentend from each other. Compute the probability it's going to rain on **at least k days**!

Example:

1. n = 4, k = 2: n1 = 0.5, n2 = 0.5, n3 = 0.5, n4 = 0.5
2. n = 3, k = 2: n1 = 0.1, n2 = 0.2, n3 = 0.3

Solutions:

1. 0.687
2. 0.098

I'm not that good at probability calculations, so I don't really know how to compute the solutions. So my question: How are the probabilites being computed? Of which prinicipal(s) should I take use to solve the problem?

(If anything is unclear, please let me know!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go through each of the possible combinations. Let $X$ denote the number of days in which it rains.

For $n=4$ and $k=2$ there are ${4 \choose 2}=6$ ways to choose the $2$ days where it will rain. Since all the probabilities are equal, we can simply take

$$P(X=2)=6\cdot0.5^4=0.375$$

Similarly for $k=3$ there are ${4 \choose 3}=4$ ways to choose the $3$ days where it will rain. We have

$$P(X=3)=4\cdot0.5^4=0.25$$

Finally, for $k=4$ there are ${4 \choose 4}=1$ ways to choose the $4$ days where it will rain. We have

$$P(X=3)=0.5^4=0.0625$$

All together,

$$P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4)=0.6875$$

Can you solve number $(2)$ noting that there are $3$ ways to get $2$ successes and $1$ way to get $3$ successes? Since not all of the probabilities are $0.5$ you'll have to account for complimentary events.

Comment: Ah.. So for ex. 2 it would be: n1*n2*(1-n3) + n1*(1-n2)*n3 + (1-n1)*n2*n3 + n1*n2*n3 = 0.098

Comment: That is correct!